# How to handle group of function to prevent it from fire in same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lot of functions that fires when window scroll I want to handle it to improve the performance and because sometimes I get this error maximum call stack excess

Comment: Look into `debounce`

Comment: what do you mean?